# Which ubuntu flavour is better for an old lap?

Tags: 19.04

i have an old laptop with intel i3 core in it.i want to use it for a time being.it do gets heated up if i run many applications.so can u suggest me which flavour of ubuntu is better?

Comment: There are variants with lighter desktops like Lubuntu, Xubuntu or even Ubuntu-Mate but if the problem is too many apps running make it overheat, it won't make much difference. Perhaps better to adjust your usage to the machine, regardless of the variant.

Comment: okay thanks.but i have another question.it has only 3gb of ram.can i use kubuntu?

Comment: You can but that is one of the variants that needs the most resources.

Comment: does the normal ubuntu gnome take up a lot of ram?

Comment: It takes more than my suggestions above but everything else is subjective.

Comment: thank you i think ill go with xubuntu/mate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 1):

Linux in general is MUCH lighter weight than Windows. If your old iron is a quad i3, that's more than enough to run Cinnamon or Mate (Gnome Desktop branches).

If you want to go ultra-light, Lxde or Xfce are both great and both lightweight. Lxde is newer, Xfce is more mature. You can install them both and then pick one to try out at boot time.

Depending on your GPU you might even be able to run Unity or KDE with all of the effects without any trouble.

Bottom line: if you have the disk space, install a few desktops that you like the look and feel of and see what happens. Chances are, they'll run fine.